# Seeking an explanation of Rashi to Ⅱ Chronicles 6:25

Tags: rashi, book-of-chronicles

In Ⅱ *Divre Hayamim* 6:24–25, translated according to *Rashi*'s reading of it, *Sh'lomo* asks *Hashem*:

> And if Your people, Israel, will be beaten before an enemy because [Israel] will have sinned to you, and they return [to You] and admit [their sins] to You and pray and implore You in this house, then You should listen from heaven, forgive the sin of Your nation, Israel, and return them to the land that You have given them and their ancestors.

On the phrase "to the land", *Rashi* comments:

> Because, when they fall and are beaten before their enemies, they grab what they can and bring them in (the?) captivity to another land.

Huh? Okay, so obviously the verse is saying the Jews are taken captive to another land. Is *Rashi* adding that the captives take material goods with them also? that the captors do? And who cares? I mean, why does *Rashi* say this?

Answer (score 4):

Continue to verses 36–39 and all will become clear:

> When [the Jews] will sin to You… and You will place them before an enemy, and their captors will capture them to a distant or near land, and [the Jews] will return their hearts in the land where they'll have been captured….

*Those* verses speak of captivity. Verse 24 doesn't say the Jews were captured at all! Why, then, does verse 25 speak of returning to the land? That's what *Rashi* is answering: Even when there isn't a real captivity, the enemies "grab what [people] they can".